# How to write generic code to open a form by instantiating the underlying class associated with the form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I think this would be classed as an advanced access question.

I am trying to write generic code to open a form by instantiating the underlying class associated with the form.  I don't know which type to use when passing the "form class" in as a parameter.

I think the "mocked up example" code below explains my question better :

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub OpenAllMyForms()

    ' I have three access forms named MyFormName1, MyFormName2 and MyFormName3
    ' Say I use this code to open all three of them

    Form_Open_MyFormName1
    ' Form_Open_MyFormName2     ' In this example I have not included the procedure used to open MyFormName2 and MyFormName3
    ' Form_Open_MyFormName3

End Sub

Function Form_Open_MyFormName1() As Form

    '
    ' Current Code  (Each form that gets opened has a function like this)
    '

    Dim frm As Form

    Set frm = New Form_MyFormName1

    ' Note that the Form_ is very significant.
    ' The form name in the access navigation pane is shown as "MyFormName1"
    ' preceeding this name with "Form_" causes the underlying class to be returned
    ' which is implements the access "Form" class.  (I think this is how you say it in OO speak)


    ' I then add this form to a collection, but lets not complicate the example
    ' clnOfForms_MyFormName1.add Item:=frm, Key:=CStr(frm.Hwnd)

    Set Form_Open_MyFormName1 = frm

    frm.Visible = True

    Set frm = Nothing

End Function


Sub OpenAllMyFormsNEW()
    '
    ' I want to write a generic function that will open any form
    ' so I replace the sub OpenAllMyForms (ie above) with this sub.
    ' I no longer have a "Form_Open_MyFormName1" function for each form
    ' but instead use Form_Open - see below.

    Dim Frm1 As Form
    Dim Frm2 As Form
    Dim Frm3 As Form

    '
    ' Note that the Form_ is very significant.
    ' The form name in the access navigation pane is shown as "MyFormName1"
    ' preceeding this name with "Form_" causes the underlying class to be returned
    '
    Set Frm1 = Form_Open(aForm:=Form_MyFormName1)
    Set Frm2 = Form_Open(aForm:=Form_MyFormName2)
    Set Frm3 = Form_Open(aForm:=Form_MyFormName3)

End Sub

Function Form_Open(aFormClass As WhatTypeShouldIuseHere) As Form

    '
    ' Here is the new function, however I don't know how to get it to work.
    ' I don't know what type to use for the parameter aFormClass see "WhatTypeShouldIuseHere" above.
    '

    Dim frm As Form

    Set frm = New aFormClass

    Set Form_Open = frm

    Set frm = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is the class itself.

But don't spend too much time on this. Access uses objects and classes but it is not OOP. If you strive for fancy programming, VBA is not for you.

You can reach a certain point using WithEvents. Little documentation on this topic, but this blog should get you started:

[Browse to A Little History](http://jwcolby.blogspot.dk/)

Problem is, that when you drive this technique *too far*, Access just crashes. And don't expect this to be corrected; MS consider not Access as a developer environment, rather a tool for superusers and SharePoint.

So look for *Visual Studio* which will honour your efforts and not waste your time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I think that is very good advise as I am already coming across difficulties.  Time for me to learn VS I think. That link is a very good article.  Just what I need to read.... Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Gustav. I just opened another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611912/how-best-to-call-a-public-sub-routine-declared-in-a-form-used-as-the-source-obje)  on which I would value you input.  I think the issue it discussed highlight a key failing in the use of access subforms, which I feel should be changed.  Please let me know what you think.