# How best to call a public sub routine declared in a form used as the source object a subform control from the main form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form MyForm1  with a module having the method.

```
Public Sub CreateSQL(ProductID as variant) 

    Me.Recordsource = " SELECT * FROM ProductOrders " _ 
                      " WHERE ProductID = " & Nz(ProductID ,0)    

    Me.Requery

End Sub
```

I use this as a subform to a form named MyMainForm.

When I change the value of a control on MyMainForm it successfully executes the following line:

```
Me.Subform1.Form.CreateSQL ProductID:=Me.cboProductID
```

**My Questions:**

1. Why are the members not listed on the intellisense list  that appears after I type `Me.Subform1.Form.`?
2. Is there a way of getting them to be listed?
3. Is there a property that will let me access the "Form_MyForm1" class of the form referenced in the subform control "Source object property"   (ie the Me.Subform1.form )  ?

It's like I need to be able to write:

```
Me.Subform1.Form_MyForm1.CreateSQL   ProductID:=Me.cboProductID
```

Does such a property already exist? If so how do I access it? Is it in the properties collection?

**PS:** If you need more information please see the same questions posted in a long Stack overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606432/the-ms-access-subform-control-intellisense-does-not-list-all-form-class-members)

Harvey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead to the mainform calling the method Me.Subform1.Form.CreateSQL

You should create an object variable in the subform that points to the main form and responds to events eg:

```
Dim WithEvents cvMyParentForm As Form

Property Set MyParentForm(MyParentForm As Form)

    Set cvMyParentForm = MyParentForm

End Property
Property Get MyParentForm() As Form

    Set MyParentForm = cvMyParentForm

End Property
```

When the main form opens use the Form_Open event to "initialise" the subforms

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    If Me.Subform1.Form.MyParentForm Is Nothing Then
        Set Me.Subform1.Form.MyParentForm = Me
    End If

End Sub
```

then you can get the subform to respond to the FORM events that are raised by the  mainform.

If you need to have the subform respond to any events that you declare in the main form you will need to chnaeg the above code to use the Form_MyMainFormname type

```
Dim WithEvents cvMyParentForm As Form_MyMainFormName

Property Set MyParentForm(MyParentForm As Form_MyMainFormName)

    Set cvMyParentForm = MyParentForm

End Property
Property Get MyParentForm() As Form_MyMainFormName

    Set MyParentForm = cvMyParentForm

End Property

Private Sub cvMyParentForm_Current()

    'MsgBox "Sub form current event - does syncing"

    Me.Form.Recordset.FindFirst "ID = " & Nz(cvMyParentForm.ID, 0)
    If Me.Form.Recordset.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "Humph"
    Else

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub cvMyParentForm_MyEvent()

    MsgBox "A user define event 'MyEvent' was fired on the  main form"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't know.
2. Not that I know of.
3. Make the subfunction Public.

But it looks like you could save yourself a lot of trouble by using the *Master/Child link option* of a form and its subform control.

Comment: The subfunction is public already.  I do use the master/Child link, but in this case I want to encapsulate code relating to the form MyForm1 in it's module and use it to set the recordsource.

Comment: Then it should work, though I can't see why you don't just include ProductId in the master/link fields. You won't need Me.Requery - it will be forced whenever you change the recordsource.

Comment: This is only a simple example.  For example, in one of my forms, a subform is filtered to a value stored on another subform.  (I believe Me.requery is not needed in Acces 2013 onwards) .  It does work, but intellisense doesn't! and hence I am breaking the object model somehow.

Comment: If it works, it should be OK. IntelliSense in VBA is extremely basic compared to the level of, say, Visual Studio.

Comment: there's more to this than meets the eye.   It's like I need to be able to write:

    Me.Subform1.Form_MyForm1.CreateSQL   ProductID:=Me.cboProductID

in order to reference these objects correctly

Comment: A better approach is to move such code to the parent form. You never run the subform on its own anyway, and it is much easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: That breaks the OO encapsulation principal.... and makes spagetti code.... and I like making subforms so they can be used in both reports and forms or independently....

Comment: Access is not an OO tool. You have classes and so, but that's about it. If you aim higher - and I sure understand that - don't waste your time with Access but move to Visual Studio where _everything_ is for development. The Community and Express versions are free and very powerful. Further, in Access, you would never use a form inside a report.

Comment: You can use a form inside a report, if you want to.... I know what you're saying about VS.  However, sometime I need to enhance an existing access db, and using forms and reports and object can be very useful